# Visual C++ error while installing Python SASL

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, sasl

I need to query into hive using python.

Currently I am using this source code.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Setting+Up+HiveServer2#SettingUpHiveServer2-PythonClientDriver

Issue is dependences for running this query is SASL and Thrift wrappers.

While installing the SASL package I am getting this error.

```
setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing sasl.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to sasl.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to sasl.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'sasl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'sasl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
building '_saslwrapper' extension
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Isasl -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC /Tpsasl/saslwrapper.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\sasl/saslwrapper.objsaslwrapper.cpp
c:\users\admin\desktop\dddd\sasl-0.1.3.tar\dist\sasl-0.1.3\sasl-0.1.3\sasl\saslwrapper.h(20) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdint.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Please provide a solution.

My environment: Win 7 64bit

Comment: Fixed typos, improved readability

Comment: Unfortunately, I have been getting the similar error, and it persists on Windows 8.1 64-bit system too. Will post if any progress.